# Autologging into a website using bookmarklet not working

Tags: javascript

Prewarning, I do not know any Javascript at all. I am just putting 2 and 2 together from other people's code to see what works.

I am trying to use a bookmarklet to auto login into an internal company website but the code doesn't seem to be working.

I can get it to auto fill the username and password field using the code below:

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_loginControl_UserName').value='USERNAME';document.getElementById('ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_loginControl_Password').value='PASSWORD';})();
```

But when I try to use this code to automatically log me in as well by submitting the log in button:

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_loginControl_UserName').value='USERNAME';document.getElementById('ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_loginControl_Password').value='PASSWORD';document.getElementsByClassName('LoginSubmit')[0].submit();
```

It doesn't just not work, it doesn't fill in the username and password any more. I have tried changing the code to get the element ID and also the class ID to use them to automate logging in, but still no dice.

I have put the code below for the 'Log In' button element from the internal work page:

```
<input type="button" name="ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$loginControl$LoginButton" value="Log In" onclick="this.disabled=true;__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$loginControl$LoginButton','')" id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_loginControl_LoginButton" class="LoginSubmit">
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use .click() instead of .submit()

Comment: Did you surround the input button with a <form > </form> pair? And you should use `<input type="submit" ... ` for a submit button.

Comment: Ahh sorry, and of cause the input text fields must be declared inside the form tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be sure unless I know how the `__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$loginControl$LoginButton','')` works, but try changing `submit()` to `click()`

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_loginControl_UserName').value='USERNAME';document.getElementById('ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_loginControl_Password').value='PASSWORD';document.getElementById('ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_loginControl_LoginButton').click();
```